# How to override user input on Jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a simple autocomplete function that searches an array of objects. It's working fine, but I want to override what the user is searching for.

I want to **append another input's value to their search**. For example, if they search "cat", I want to append `$('#input2').val()` so their search becomes "cat dog" (without changing the actual <input>'s value).

This seems like an easy thing to do, but I can't figure out how to do it without overriding the entire search method.

**Existing code:**

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: data,
    appendTo: '#admin-results'
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $('<li>')
  .append('<div>' + item.label + '</div>')
  .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: `source` can be function  http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: @charlietfl Appears OP is trying to modify input value passed to `.autocomplete()`

Comment: @guest271314 I read *"without change input value"*

Comment: You can pass adjusted concatenated value of `input` elements to  modified version of `typeahead.js` `substringMatcher` function, see [How to send data in request body when using Typeahead & Bloodhound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739881/how-to-send-data-in-request-body-when-using-typeahead-bloodhound/)

Comment: @charlietfl `.typeahead.js`s [`substringMatcher`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jharding/9458744/raw/94c98ffbb7496ce16ac8067dd5b2867182ea4c04/the-basics.js) function can be modified and utilized instead of `.autocomplete()`, `.typeahead()`; where any value can be passed to the function.

Comment: @guest271314 works fine as function http://plnkr.co/edit/ivOaZQY9mZ1LlTKptVsJ?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl I'm trying to change search query behind the scenes, without showing the user that it was modified (I don't want to change the actual <input>'s value). It looks like I can use a custom `source` function and override `request.term`, but I don't want to define my own `response` function.

Comment: @charlietfl Attempted to convey that the `substringMatcher` function can be used without loading an entire plugin. Instead use `input` event, and the function, where any value can be passed as input.

Comment: I guess I'm missing the whole point of exercise. However can easily be done by writing own filter and pass to `resposne()` as shown in link above

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks so much! Your plnkr demo is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do what you ask by using function for source

```
var terms = ["c++", "java dog", "php dog", "coldfusion", "javascript dog", "asp dog", "ruby"]
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function(req, response) {
    var term = req.term + ' dog';// adjust to a dom value or whatever
    var res = terms.filter(function(item) {
      return item.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase()
    });
    response(res);
  }
});
```

Adjust filter function accordingly also. This is only rough for absolute match

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ivOaZQY9mZ1LlTKptVsJ?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: another approach is remove the extended  term in your filtering

Answer (score 0):

1.get the val from #admin-results. put the val into a variable "a". 
2.a = a + desiredVal
3.put the new "a" into #admin-results